# Reliably run Proxy trap _after_ the values are set

Tags: javascript

I want to create a proxy like so. I used [the Reflect.set, as the documentation seems to imply.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

```
function createStore<T>(reducer: Reducer<T>, initialState: T) {
  const store = new Proxy(initialState, {
    set(target, key, value) {
      console.log('Trap has been activated');
      return Reflect.set(target, key, value);
    }
  });
}
```

Now when I set a field, it does effectively trigger this trap. However, I want to trigger this trap *after* the values have been set. I tried this, expecting `Reflect.set` to return me a next state:

```
const nextState = Reflect.set(target, key, value);
// my code here
return nextState;
```

Instead, it returns me a boolean.

Is there any way to get the "next value" of a proxy before returning the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `Reflect.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/set) clarifies things:

> **Return value**
>
>  A Boolean indicating whether or not setting the property was successful.

If you want to get the value as it is after it's set, you can use [`Reflect.get(target, key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get) or just go directly to the target (`target[key]`):

```
function createStore<T>(reducer: Reducer<T>, initialState: T) {
  const store = new Proxy(initialState, {
    set(target, key, value) {
      console.log('Trap has been activated');
      const retVal = Reflect.set(target, key, value);
      console.log(`New value: ${Reflect.get(target, key)}`);
      return retVal;
    }
  });
}
```